# How do I make Thunderbird save attachments as .html instead of .xht?

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, attachments

I'm encountering a problem regarding handling of attachments with Thunderbird (9.0.1, Windows 7).

I've set Thunderbird to open HTML files with Firefox. But currently, Thunderbird adds a **".xht"** extension to the attachment file when saving temporarily (so, the filename "`foo.html`" now is "`foo.html.xht`") before passing it to Firefox. Thus, Firefox tries to parse the HTML file as XML and fails, since the attachments often aren't valid X(HT)ML, but old, ugly HTML.

If I save the attachment manually, Thunderbird doesn't touch the file extension, and thus Firefox doesn't have a problem displaying the "old" HTML. But when saving manually, I have to open the Windows Explorer, navigate to the download folder, and double-click manually.

So, how do I tell Thunderbird **not** to change the file name (especially the extension) when saving the file temporarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the [MozillaZine Knowledge
Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Actions_for_attachment_file_types) the problem was found to be a wrong `Content-Type` set by the sender - it was "`application/xhtml+xml`" instead of "`text/html`".  So, the easiest solution would be to tell the sender to add a content type that fits the content.

For the mail recipient, a quick-and-dirty solution would be to modify the "[mimeTypes.rtf](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf)" file that's part of the user profile. It should have an entry looking like this:

```xml
<RDF:Description RDF:about="urn:mimetype:application/xhtml+xml"
               NC:value="application/xhtml+xml"
               NC:editable="true"
               NC:fileExtensions="xht"
               NC:description="Firefox HTML Document">
    <NC:handlerProp RDF:resource="urn:mimetype:handler:application/xhtml+xml"/>
</RDF:Description>
```

Changing he value of the `NC:fileExtensions` attribute to `html`  will make Thunderbird save even  `application/xhtml+xml` attachments with 'html' file extension:

```xml
NC:fileExtensions="html"
```